# How to concatenate two string fields into one in a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[
  {"firstName": "john", "lastName": "doe", "linkedInID":"..."},   
  {"firstName": "jane", "lastName": "doe", "linkedInID":"..."},
  {"firstName": "someone", "lastName": "Mc Donald", "linkedInID":"..."},
  ...
]
```

I want it to be merged to:

```
[
  {"Name": "john doe", "linkedInID": "..."},   
  {"Name": "jane doe", "linkedInID": "..."},
  {"Name": "someone Mc Donald", "linkedInID": "..."},
  ...
]
```

All new objects should have a field `Name` which is the concatenation of `firstName` and `lastName`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Instead of changing the array, why not concat the strings when using them.

Comment: You're looking for [`[].map()`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/map)

Comment: Related: [Concatenate each object property values of javascript array , properties are list of strings in javascript](/q/71812690/4642212), [How to concatenate multiple properties of same element from an array?](/q/69056356/4642212).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you need Angular for that? One possibility is to use the native [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) javascript method in order to transform your input array:

```
var inputArray = [
    {"firstName":"john","lastName":" doe","linkedInID":"..."},   
    {"firstName":"jane","lastName":"doe","linkedInID":"..."},
    {"firstName":"someone","lastName":"Mc Donald","linkedInID":"..."},
    ...
];

var result = inputArray.map(function(item) {
    return {
        Name: item.firstName + ' ' + item.lastName,
        linkedInID: item.linkedInID
    };
});
```

Comment: An ES6 version, please? A nice arrow function!

Comment: @Kyll `inputArray.map(item => ({
    Name: item.firstName + ' ' + item.lastName,
    linkedInID: item.linkedInID
}));`

Comment: There are several equivalent alternatives, e.g. using [destructuring](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), [spread syntax](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), and [template literals](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals): ``const result = inputArray.map(({ firstName, lastName, ...rest }) => ({ Name: `${firstName} ${lastName}`, ...rest }));``.